# how to get an entity inside an other one?

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a small problem with a dotnet project where I need to use linq syntax to call a class inside another one.

table.cs

```
public class Table
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
        public int Numero { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Reservation> IReservation { get; set; }
    }
```

tablegroupe.cs

```
public class TableGroupe : Table
{
    public int NbChaise { get; set; }
}
```

tablecouple.cs

```
public class TableCouple : Table
{
    public bool DineeChandelle { get; set; }
}
```

restaurentcontext.cs

```
public class RestaurantContext :DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Table> tTable { set; get; }
        public DbSet<Menu> tMenu { set; get; }
        public DbSet<Reservation> tReservation { set; get; }
        public RestaurantContext() : base("RestaurentDB") {
            
        }
```

tablerepository.cs

```
class TableRepository
    {
        RestaurantContext rc = null;

    public TableRepository()
    {
        rc = new RestaurantContext();
    }
    public void Commit()
    {
        rc.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void AddTable(Table m)
    {
        rc.tTable.Add(m);
    }
    public TableCouple GetFirstTableCoupleAvailable(bool chandelle) {}
}
```

I couldn't know how to get the table which is tablecouple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 classes that are derived from Table.

```
tablegroupe
tablecouple
```

Your table class is your baseClass I think (?).
In your context you want to add the other tables instead of the base class.

```
public class RestaurantContext :DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TableGroupe> tTableGroupe { set; get; }
    public DbSet<TableCouple> tTableCouple { set; get; }
    public DbSet<Menu> tMenu { set; get; }
    public DbSet<Reservation> tReservation { set; get; }
    public RestaurantContext() : base("RestaurentDB") {
 }
```

You might want to make your Table class abstract (or virtual). Or if I misunderstsood, then you want to add Table also to your context... But then I would suggest you create an interface for base class.

Comment: your welcome! One other suggestion is to keep table_names clear => TableGroupe and not tTableGroupe. Even for views you want to keep it. If someone has questions about an entity, they want to go to the entity and with data-attributes they can see it is a view (or something else).